# Cross-number puzzle

Tags: mathematics, crosswords

[image]

**ACROSS:**

A. a square

C. a multiple of N Across

E. (C Down) $\times$ (I Across)

G. a square root of A Down

I. a square root of D Down

J. (J Across) $\times$ (K Across) = (F Down) $\times$ (M Down)

K. (J Across) $\times$ (K Across) = (F Down) $\times$ (M Down)

L. a divisor of H Down

N. a divisor of O Down

P. a divisor of I Down

R. a multiple of P Down

S. a square of Q Down

**DOWN:**

A. a square of G Across

B. a square

C. not a square

D. $1000-$(A Across)

F. a power

H. (L Across) $\times$ (N Across)

I. a multiple of P Across

L. (P Down) $\times$ (Q Down)

M. a power

O. a multiple of N Across

P. a divisor of R Across

Q. a square root of S Across

**Edit:**

No numbers begin with digit 0 and all numbers are different. So the correct answer should contain twelve distinct 2-digit numbers and twelve distinct 3-digit numbers.

Comment: what do you mean by "a square of ___" or "a power"?

Comment: @Alto "a square of G Across" means "(G Across) $\times$ (G Across)". "Power" means square, cube, etc.

Comment: Oh, then. "a power" could be any number! because in x^y, y can be anything. Yay! -edit Got that.

Comment: @Alto $y$ is an integer bigger than or equal to 2.

Comment: Nice puzzle! $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer:

> I didn't really use a whole lot of logic to solve this. It was mostly a couple educated guesses and a whole lot of trial and error.
>
> ```
> 324 376
> 6 988 7
> 19 1 26
>  48 54 
> 20 3 47
> 9 122 9
> 781 729
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Technically, I think I have a cheaterpants solution to this:

> [image]

I will definitely try to find a better answer though.

Comment: NOOOOOO!!! I have to solve this! Fast!!! [jk, but you're so fast! how do you do it?] Good job, nice. Also, there's no rule against it, so you're good to go.

Comment: Noooooo! 00 is not allowed.

Comment: But, I wonder how he can find (almost) all numbers so fast.

Comment: @P.-S.Park Well when someone has more than 12K reputation, it's not really a surprise that he's a master :D

Comment: @KevinL Haha. I agree. :-)

Comment: @KevinL El-Guest is indomitable; unbeatable; undefeatable; invincible; unsurpassable; unassailable; unstoppable; etc. Know why? Because all those words end in **le**. Put it backwards and you get **el** for **El**-Guest :P

Comment: @user477343 I'd say that's 110% true mate :D

Comment: @user477343 I appreciate the sentiment!! You’re so kind, thank you! :D

Comment: @El-Guest No problem. I said what was true :)

Comment: That comment was actually pretty funny, to be honest, hahah :P

Comment: Well I really appreciate it regardless — you both always create some very creative compliments!!

Comment: It is surprising how close your solution is to my answer. You probably would have gotten it quicker then me if you didn't mess up H down. It should be 940 not 980.

Comment: @BennettBernardoni oh dear, that’s exactly what I get for doing a puzzle after being awake for 20 hours haha. Good that you got it! :)